# Plsql Package errors

Tags: plsql

The below code is getting many errors. Just want to check if my code syntax is correct. The main logic behind the package is to get all the cases for particular review and spool it to a file using shell script. As of now, am concentrating on the package .

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY  PK_FCP_EXTRACT is

PROCEDURE sp_fcp_extract is

     cursor Rev_cur is select * from t_uar_reviews where CREATED_DATE=trunc(sysdate) ;
       r Rev_cur%rowtype;
      cursor case_cur( c_revid IN t_uar_reviews.review_id%type )
          is select *
               from t_uar_cases where review_id= c_revid ;
     c case_cur%rowtype;
   begin
    open Rev_cur;
    loop
       fetch Rev_cur into r;
       exit when Rev_cur%notfound;
       open case_cur( r.review_id );
       loop
         fetch case_cur into c;
         exit when case_cur%notfound;
         dbms_output.put_line(c.UAR_CASE_ID||','||c.UAR_REVIEW_ID||','||c.CASE_TYPE||','||c.CASE_NMBR||','||c.ACTIVE_FLAG||','|| c.CREATED_DATE);
       end loop;
       close case_cur;
     end loop;
     close Rev_cur;
  end;

END PK_FCP_EXTRACT;
```

Comment: What are the "many errors" in detail? [Edit] the question and add the messages.

Comment: Error(6,7): PL/SQL: Item ignored
Error(6,49): PLS-00302: component 'REVIEW_ID' must be declared
Error(9,8): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Error(9,8): PL/SQL: Item ignored
Error(15,8): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Please add the errors into the question so others can see then easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct.

The following test code works correctly in an empty schema:

```
create table t_uar_reviews(
  review_id number,
  created_date date
)
/
create table t_uar_cases(
  review_id number,
  UAR_CASE_ID number,
  UAR_REVIEW_ID number,
  CASE_TYPE varchar2(10),
  CASE_NMBR number,
  active_flag varchar2(1),
  created_date date)
/

create package PK_FCP_EXTRACT is
  PROCEDURE sp_fcp_extract;
end;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY  PK_FCP_EXTRACT is

PROCEDURE sp_fcp_extract is

     cursor Rev_cur is select * from t_uar_reviews where CREATED_DATE=trunc(sysdate) ;
       r Rev_cur%rowtype;
      cursor case_cur( c_revid IN t_uar_reviews.review_id%type )
          is select *
               from t_uar_cases where review_id= c_revid ;
     c case_cur%rowtype;
   begin
    open Rev_cur;
    loop
       fetch Rev_cur into r;
       exit when Rev_cur%notfound;
       open case_cur( r.review_id );
       loop
         fetch case_cur into c;
         exit when case_cur%notfound;
         dbms_output.put_line(c.UAR_CASE_ID||','||c.UAR_REVIEW_ID||','||c.CASE_TYPE||','||c.CASE_NMBR||','||c.ACTIVE_FLAG||','|| c.CREATED_DATE);
       end loop;
       close case_cur;
     end loop;
     close Rev_cur;
  end;

END PK_FCP_EXTRACT;
```

Possible causes of trouble:

- Make sure that the package spec has been created first (`CREATE PACKAGE`)
- Ensure that the package is created in the schema that owns `t_uar_reviews` and `t_uar_cases`, or in a schema that has a *direct* `SELECT` grant on the tables (not via a role).
- Make sure all of the columns you reference in the package exist in the tables.

If those are all done, it should work.

To simplify things, try using this alternate syntax for your cursor loops:

```
for r in Rev_cur loop
  for c in Case_cur(r.review_id) loop
    ...do something..
  end loop;
end loop;
```

By using this method, you do not need to define the record `r` or `c`; they are implicitly created, and you do not to open/fetch/check/close the cursors.

Comment: I made a mistake. Its the column name which i have given incorrect. Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd also suggest combining the two cursors into one result set with a JOIN.  The current code is effectively joining in PL/SQL, which will be slow.